# Apache Pig conditional foreach generate

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I'm trying to implement a conditional foreach generate where one of the columns data changes depending on the input data.

Say for example I have this data in alias A:

```
dump A;
(George, Films)
(Martin, Books)
```

I want to store an Y if the name starts with G. From the [documentation](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#relations) I know there is a conditional arithmetic operation but I cannot find the way to do the 'starts with X' thing. I think it should be something like this where ##### is the missing condition.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (##### ? "Y":"N");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the SUBSTRING function. Use it like this:

```
b = foreach a generate $0.., (SUBSTRING($0,0,1)=='G'?'y':'n');
```

Read more about it here

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#substring

it would give you

```
(George,Films,y)
(Martin,Books,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply UDFs within `GENERATE`:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE MyUdf(name);
```

Where `MyUdf` is a function you write to perform the logic you want. I'm not aware of a way to do this without UDFs.